# Hough circle detection: Blurring the image before calling hough circle algorithm?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision, hough-transform

http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.org/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_imgproc/py_houghcircles/py_houghcircles.html

In the example here, I do not know why it called the median filter first before the hough circle algorithm. Is this meant to give better detection?

Also, is there any other tricks in general that maybe useful when calling Hough circle algorithm? In particular, if the circular object has same brightness with its background, hence looking homogeneous on the grey scale, is there anything I can do here?

Also, if I cannot get perfect detection, I would prefer having less detected circles but rather the detected ones are correct.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The blur will help avoid false circle detection by reducing noise, because openCV uses a gradient version of the hough circle detection algorithm, outlined here: http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/BOOKS/BANDB/LIB/bandb4_3.pdf

The size of the blur will interplay with the upper threshold for the internal Canny edge detector, which is param_1. You'll want to play around with that.

To get around the brightness problem, try detecting just with isolated R, G and B channels. To get more complete results, you can then shift hue by 60 and then use isolated channels again.

Comment: great answer thank you. Can I be curious what does "shift hue by 60" do?

Comment: Quick, crude example: http://imgur.com/CGB1W58.
Top left: original image,
Bottom left: desaturated original, top right: hue + 60. Bottom right: desaturated the hue+60 version. Sometimes things become apparent in greyscale or in individual RGB channels after you shift hue by 60. Why 60? Because it splits right between the channels. 120 just shuffles the channels around, but gives you nothing new.

Comment: Whether that gets you any better circle recognition in practice, I can't really say. I just know it is a very simple and crude way to bring out information you can't find in the greyscale or isolated channels.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but Hue and the greyscale intensity is independent, no? I thought in HSV, H, S and V are independent and V are the green scale intensity.

Comment: Or you mean to input Hue itself as the greyscale intensity for the grey image?

Comment: If you just use the "V" from your HSV image, then yes, you are 100% correct. But that's not the only way to get a grayscale. Take a look at the images here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HSL_and_HSV#Disadvantages to see some quick examples. In open CV, you can take the max of (r,g,b) to define your greyscale, you can take the average of (r,g,b), or many other options. These options can be affected by hue fairly dramatically, and shifting hue makes a difference. If you're just taking the V, then the hue shift won't do anything.

Comment: Main point is to at least try your different R / G / B channels, not just V. That will get you pretty far if you're worried about things that don't show up in just the V channel.

Comment: what do you mean by "size of the blur will interplay with the upper threshold for the internal Canny"? in your experience, what is a good size to choose?

Comment: The thresholds in the edge detection are what determine what is considered a "strong edge", a "weak edge", and not an edge at all. The upper threshold determines what it takes to constitute a strong edge. As you do a Gaussian pass, you'll be doing two things. First, removing noise, which lowers the chance of false positives. That's a common step for edge detection. But you'll also be decreasing the contrast between adjacent pixels, which means you'll need to detect smaller differences in order to read an edge.

Comment: As far as what's a good size to choose, that's totally dependent on the source imagery. A common blur setting is a 5x5 matrix. If you're doing real-time stuff, remember that the larger your blur matrix, the slower it will be. You'll have to play with the parameters to get good performance and the right balance between few false positives and few false negatives for your application.

Comment: Take with a grain of salt. I haven't visited this topic in a few years.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is meant to reduce the noise within the image, with the aim to improve edge detection. Edge detection algorithms are sensitive to noise.

Described here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Median_filter

But this image better illustrates how blur improves (even your brain's) edge detection:
https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/62/Cappadocia_Gaussian_Blur.svg

This image is from an article on Gaussian Blur, another smoothing technique that reduces noise in signals (like images). However, Median Filter preserves edges better than Gaussian Blur, hence its use in image processing. (Described under "Edge preservation properties" in Wiki's Median Filter article)